# In Swift, use a global CodingKeys (enum or struct) keeping my objects as simple as possible

Tags: json, swift, mapping, jsonencoder

In a simplified example, I have these JSONs Strings

```
let jsonStringBird = """
{
    "identifier": "0001ABX",
    "name": "Doroty",
    "species_name": "Gorrion",
}
"""


let jsonStringPlane = """
{
    "identifier": "PL1803",
    "name": "Boing 777",
    "number_sits_in_plane": 8,
}
"""
```

And I have a lot of structures like these ones (they are just examples)

```
struct Bird: Decodable {
    var identifier: String
    var name: String
    var species: String
}

struct Plane: Decodable {
    var identifier: String
    var name: String
    var sits: String
}
```

So, I want to decode my structs without modify them (avoid overriding the `init from decoder` method and avoid having a `private CodingKeys enum`).

Maybe having a **global CodingKey enum/struct** like this one, but I don't know how to tell to the JSONDecoder to use the following CodingKey for all my structs (I only know how to do it in the `init from decoder` method)

```
enum MyCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case identifier
    case name
    case species = "species_name"
    case sits = "number_sits_in_plane"
}
```

My point is that I have a lot of those structures, and I would prefer to keep them as simple as posible

**Notes**

In my real project I'm actually using CBORCoding where I'm mapping `[Int, AnyCodable]` properties, not `[String, AnyCodable]`.

So, for the question here is important to use JSONDecoder and use CodingKeys. That way I could translate it to CBORCoding

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson. However, in my real project I'm mapping [Int, AnyCodable] properties, not [String, AnyCodable]. So, the enum CodingKeys is mandatory. I just wrote it in this way to simplify my question sorry

Comment: try to make it clearer what part of your question is a fixed specification and what is variable in design. Then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: There is no such thing as a global CodingKey enum, the question is changing all the time but as I see it you need to implement a CodingKey enum for each type that requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with `JSONSerialization` that works with your example.

**+** it does not need any `CodingKey`.

**+** it is totally flexible with what and how many attributes your object will have.

**-** all attributes are stored in a dictionary with the values of type `Any`.

**-** only one object type.

```
struct myObject {
    let identifier: String
    let name: String
    let attributes: [String: Any]
}

func myObjectFromJSON(_ jsonString: String) -> myObject? {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    
    if var json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
        print(type(of: json), json) // Dictionary<String, Any> ["species_name": Gorrion, "identifier": 0001ABX, "name": Doroty]
        
        if let identifier = json["identifier"] as? String, let name = json["name"] as? String {
            json.removeValue(forKey: "identifier")
            json.removeValue(forKey: "name")
            let newObject = myObject(identifier: identifier, name: name, attributes: json)
            return newObject
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Usage:

```
let object1 = myObjectFromJSON(jsonStringBird)
let object2 = myObjectFromJSON(jsonStringPlane)
```

Comment: Thank you. In my real project I'm mapping [Int, AnyCodable] properties using CBORDecoder, similar how JSONDecoder does. So, the enum CodingKeys is mandatory. I will update my question with more details